# Entropy in mole fraction distribution

Tags: distributions, entropy

I am studying how mole fractions are distributed in real life fuels (summation of mole fractions for any fuel=1, always). In this regard, I was trying to see if I can correlate my observations to theory - like entropy maximization. For summation(mole fractions)=1, mole fractions would follow a dirichlet distribution, for example. I saw in dirichlet wikipedia information about a term called "entropy". Is this entropy in some way related to physical/ chemical entropy, which can be used to derive the distribution with the highest chance?